# Codeblocks compiles, GCC does not

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, g++, codeblocks

I have a C++ program, about 7 header files and 7 `.cpp` files all jammed into one directly. If I attempt to compile it in CodeBlocks, everything works fine and dandy. No problems at all.

However, I'm trying to get it to work under a Unix command line. I'm doing a basic compile by typing

```
g++ main.cpp
```

This should produce a file called `a.out` (by default), which I am to run.

However, I get a load of undefined reference errors. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: What about the other 6 .cpp files?

Comment: The undefined reference errors are for each of my destructors and a few random methods.

Comment: If main.cpp uses functions in other source files, you'll need to list them when invoking g++.

Comment: he means why aren't you telling g++ about your other 6 .cpp files

Comment: Oh...@JamesMcLaughlin, I'm guessing by your comment I need to compile all of them.. how would I do this, just list them all off?

Comment: *about 7 header files and 7 .cpp files all jammed into one directly* does this mean you copy-pasted 14 files into one file?

Comment: @yannbane No, they're just not in folders, they're all located in the same directory

Comment: @user3308043 OK then please clarify your first sentence if possible, it's quite confusing.

Comment: @user3308043 Yes, list them all.

Comment: are you using "g++ file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp .... " etc??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find this question strange because CodeBlocks uses G++.

When you compile with the command line `g++`, you need to specify all the source files that need compiling and linking:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp file1.cpp file2.cpp
```

You will also need to include the libraries with the `-l` option.  The libraries depend on your OS and platform.

Comment: Does codeblocks have the option to show the commandline it is passing to g++?

Comment: I'm using Unix, how would I indicate libraries? Are any libraries included by default?

Comment: who know, who cares, it works great. thanks a lot for the command line assistance! great tip!

Comment: @MattMcNabb It may somewhere, yes, but at this point including all .cpp files, with the -o parameter and 'main' object name worked fine. Excellent suggestion though.